Problem with Docker image ROS noetic on Fedora-40
After installing Fedorа-40 OS on the workstation and running roscore in Docker container, I get a problem. After a few seconds, the RAM and swap are 90% occupied. The Gnome's graphical interface does not respond. After stopping (Ctrl+C) roscore, the memory is released and the system performance is restored. ROS - noetic version, image based on Ubuntu Focal 20.04
I tried changing the type of the ROS image - the result is the same.

This is related to the number of open file descriptors.
Already reported and resolved here.
On Fedora 40 Workstation, roslaunch was opening a lot more files than what was allowed leading to RAM + Swap running out and crashing GNOME.
Resolved this by setting hard and soft limits for allowed file descriptors in /etc/docker/daemon.json.
{
    "default-ulimits": {
        "nofile": {
            "Name": "nofile",
            "Hard": 524288,
            "Soft": 1024
        }
    }
}

Hard limit: The absolute maximum number of open file descriptors allowed.
Soft limit: The threshold at which the kernel will start sending warnings to discourage opening more files.
This is a global change for all containers, you can also pass it as docker run arguments:
docker run --ulimit nofile=1024:524288 <image-name>
